# Difference between two numpy arrays of tuples

Tags: python, numpy, compare, tuples, unique

I have got numpy ndarray `wall` which consists of tuples `brick = (x, y, w, h)`.

It looks like

```
[[317. 276.  17.  12.]
[317. 276.  17.  12.]
[317. 276.  17.  12.]
[248. 276.  25.  17.]
[320. 274.  18.  13.]
[353. 273.  15.  11.]
[377. 272.  17.  11.]
[  0. 271.  61.  71.]
[ 21. 266.  75.  49.]
[228. 280.  20.  14.]
[306. 245.  15.  20.]
[519. 239.  18.  18.]
[482. 252.  22.  10.]]
```

I would like to eliminate the same ones, as you can see first three are identical. After that with every new iteration (camera callback - frame receive) I've got new `wall`. I would like to compare this with old one and find the difference, basically find all different `brick`. Unfortunately intersection/unique or other strict methods didn't work for me. Any hints will be appreciated.

Comment: [`np.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) does have an `axis` argument, so could you elaborate why you can't use that? Also I don't understand why you have an array of tuples as opposed to a 2D array (which you seem to have, according to the output you show).

Comment: because I receive `wall` as result of `cv2.trackers.update`. The problem I can't solve is that `np.unique` returns 1D array with all unique elements, not unique bricks.

Comment: Notice that the dot in each number means that your array has float numbers. It you only have integers, pass `dtype=int` when creating the array to have an array of integers.

Comment: Isn't that what you want? In case your array is of `dtype=object` and contains the bricks as whatever objects, as long as they support `==`, you can just use `np.unique(a)` and it will give you an array of unique brick objects. From your question it appears this is what you've asked for. If not, could you please update your question with reproducible (i.e. copy & pasteable) code together with expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question and comments it appears that you want to remove unique elements along the first axis. You can do so via [`np.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) by specifying `axis=0`:

```
np.unique(wall, axis=0)
```

If `wall.dtype is object` and stores some kind of `brick` objects, as long as they support equality checks `==` (`__eq__`), you can just use `np.unique(a)`.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas is a great library for this. Might not be the most efficient way, but it gets the job done.

```
import pandas as pd

tmp = [
    [317, 276,  17,  12.],
    [317, 276,  17,  12.],
    [317, 276,  17,  12.],
    [248, 276,  25,  17.],
    [320, 274,  18,  13.],
    [353, 273,  15,  11.],
    [377, 272,  17,  11.],
    [  0, 271,  61,  71.],
    [ 21, 266,  75,  49.],
    [228, 280,  20,  14.],
    [306, 245,  15,  20.],
    [519, 239,  18,  18.],
    [482, 252,  22,  10.]
]

df = pd.DataFrame(tmp).drop_duplicates()
```

Output is:

```
    0   1   2   3
0   317 276 17  12.0
3   248 276 25  17.0
4   320 274 18  13.0
5   353 273 15  11.0
6   377 272 17  11.0
7   0   271 61  71.0
8   21  266 75  49.0
9   228 280 20  14.0
10  306 245 15  20.0
11  519 239 18  18.0
12  482 252 22  10.0
```

Comment: that seems to be legit, will try this way.

Comment: How is that different to using `np.unique(a, axis=0)`?

Comment: Pandas will keep the rows organised, where numpy won't. If this is not a problem, then the numpy approach might be better indeed.

Comment: Well, actually  after test `np.unique(a,axis=0)`  works best for me. thanks a lot, guys.